# Hide folder name from particular URL using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I had a root folder and a subdirectory in it. My project is in subdirectory. I want to show that subdirectory in all my urls except for one page which is show_film.php

I want it to be

```
www.xyz.com/show_film/
```

instead of

```
www.xyz.com/subdirectory/show_film/
```

I had tried

```
RewriteRule  ^show_film/$ subdirectory/show_film.php
RewriteRule  ^show_film$ subdirectory/show_film.php
```

I always get 404 error if I use the above code. I am placing the above code in root htaccess

My Root Htacess
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^abc\.in$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.abc.in/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteRule (.*)\.xml(.*) $1.php$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\.ico|sitemap\.xml|\.css|\.js|\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|robots\.txt)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(category)
RewriteRule .? - [S=6]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/page/)
RewriteRule .? - [S=2]
RewriteRule ^category/(.*)/page/(.*)/$ index.php?action=category&slug=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^category/(.*)/page/(.*)$ http://%1/category/$1/page/$2/ [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/$ index.php?action=category&slug=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ index.php?action=category [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ http://%1/$1/$2/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(tag)
RewriteRule .? - [S=6]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/page/)
RewriteRule .? - [S=2]
RewriteRule ^tag/(.*)/page/(.*)/$ index.php?action=tag&slug=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^tag/(.*)/page/(.*)$ http://%1/tag/$1/page/$2/ [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/$ index.php?action=tag&slug=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ index.php?action=tag [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ http://%1/$1/$2/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(blog)
RewriteRule .? - [S=7]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/page/)
RewriteRule .? - [S=2]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/page/(.*)/$ index.php?action=blog&page=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/page/(.*)$ http://%1/$1/page/$2/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/$ http://%1/$2/ [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^blog$ http://%1/blog/ [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ index.php?action=blog [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ http://%1/$2/ [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/$ index.php?action=blog&slug=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (ajax|sitemap)
RewriteRule .? - [S=2]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ index.php?action=blog&slug=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?action=$1 [L,QSA]

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^abc\.in$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.abc\.in$
RewriteRule ^post\/goa\-government\-websites\-hacked\-allegedly\-palestine\-hackers\/$ "http\:\/\/www\.cyberintelligence\.in\/goa\-government\-websites\-hacked\-allegedly\-palestine\-hackers\/" [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /subdir/(show_film)\.php\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^show_film/?$ /subdir/show_film.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: where to add these lines?? In root htacess or in the subdirectory htaccess @starkeen

Comment: Place it in root.htaccess.

Comment: What url are you going to?

Comment: This rule redirects **/subdir/show_file.php** to root **/show_file.php** and then internally maps the file back to subdir. its working fine on my server.

Comment: Should I have to place the code at the top of my root htaccess @starkeeen

Comment: Yes, put it at top otherwise other rules may conflict with this.

Comment: Can U plz have a look at my htacess. I put it every where but not working @starkeen

Comment: What exactly happess when you type **/subdir/show_file.php** ?

Comment: Its working but with .php in the end. I want my url as www.abc.in/show_fim/ @starkeen

Comment: hi @starkeen, I am having parameters in my url. www.xyz.com/subdirectory/show_film/reset-password/123/123
I want it to be www.xyz.com/subdirectory/reset-password/123/123 where first 123 is q and second 123 is p where p, q are query strings

Comment: @starkeen please see my problem at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42618308/url-rewriting-redirecting-restricting-on-multiple-conditions-using-htaccess