# Htaccess rewriting to root folder with parameters from sub directory

Tags: .htaccess

I am having parameters in my url.

```
 https://www.example.com/subdirectory/reset-password/123/123
```

I want it to be `https://www.example.com/reset-password/123/123`

where first 123 is first parameter and second parameter is 123

I am making the rule for the below link:
I want it to be

```
https://www.example.com/subdirectory/reset-password?p=123&q=123
```

to

```
I want it to be `https://www.example.com/reset-password/123/123`
```

I am using the following link as reference
[Hide folder name from particular URL using .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38099791/hide-folder-name-from-particular-url-using-htaccess/38100025#38100025)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^reset-password/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /subdirectory/reset-password?p=$1&q=$2 [L]
```

It will give you the following URL:

`https://www.example.com/reset-password/123/123`

Comment: what is the meaning of [L]

Comment: The [L] flag stands for "last" and causes the rewrite to stop processing the rule(s). This means that if the rule(s) match, no further rules will be processed.